# HTML default link color

Tags: html, css

I want to set color of some elements to default link color with CSS.

```
<a href="/">That color</a> is the same as <span style="color: link;">that</span>.
```

Any way to do that? This website don't change default browser's link color.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if you don't change the default color, it would still be a good idea to specify the color to ensure that it looks the same in all browsers. I'd put something like this in the stylesheet:

```
a, span.link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited, span.visited {
   color: purple;
}

a:active, span.active {
   color: red;
}
```

Then you can style `span`s as links by `<span class="link">Your fake link</span>`

Answer (score 1):

after some time messing around with testing pure css and css/javascript i'm sure you can't set the color of any other element to the default link-color of the browser - but like Machine said, you can try using classes to do this (but you won't be able to use the browser defaults, you have to set your own colors)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set to a new color for a link or to prevent the change of the color of a specific link *after* visiting it, add inside the `<a>` tag:

```
<A STYLE="text-decoration:none; color=[select your favorite...]" HREF="link.html">test link</A>
```